# Change a specific property in css using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, properties

I want the online icon to blink. Put this in my js code:

```
function blink(){
    $('ul.left_menu li.online').delay(100).fadeTo(100,0.5).delay(100).fadeTo(100,1, blink);
}
```

What happens is that the whole link is blinking. Is there any way to access a specific property in jquery?

My css:

```
ul.left_menu li.online a{
    width:166px;
    height:25px;
    display:block;
    background:url(../images/online-status.png) no-repeat left #dad0d0; 
    background-position:5px 5px;
    border-bottom:1px #FFFFFF solid;
}
```

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of specific methods to retrieve some specific properties. If you were more specific - it would be possible to answer more specific as well.

Comment: what specific properties are you speaking of?

Comment: You are saying the whole link is blinking can you share what is the expected behavior , So that a proper solution can be given , There is a Jquery CSS api to achieve such kind of functionality . here is the link for that [Jquery CSS API](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: i think he speaks about the background-url: he wants to blink the background

Comment: jQuery operates on DOM elements, not CSS properties. So you should put the CSS properties that you want to change on different elements.

Comment: Your jQuery selector is not the same as your CSS selector? In jQuery you're targeting the `li`, and in CSS you're targeting the `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to blink only the icon and not the whole link. But your JavaScript will blink the whole link because JS is assigned to your link container and you set the icon using css background. You can get rid of this using `<img>` tag. Use `<img>` to display the icon near your link, and give it a class. Assign blink to this class using jQuery.